# How to use ranges-v3 in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode

I have problems including the ranges library in Xcode. I already found out that the it doesn't exists in Xcodes include path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
so I wanted to use gcc's libs instead.
So I just added /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/ to Xcode's header search paths which lead to this error:

[image]

I assume that it is still using clang for compiling and uses the Xcode default STL still, so how can I either use gcc to compile my project or getting clang using the ranges library?

Comment: xcode really isn't designed to use a custom compiler, you're probably better off using your own copy of ranges rather than trying to persuade xcode to use libstdc++'s https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I read through the github docs but I couldn't figure out how to install and build it correctly to include it in Xcode?